# How does Rebus HTTP Gateway acknowledge message delivery

Tags: rebus

I would like to ask how does Rebus HTTP Gateway acknowledge message delivery so when OutboundService sends the message how it knows it can commit or rollback the transaction.

Intuitive answer would be that HTTP response acknowledges it however looking at the code

https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/5fef6b400feaf569e0d6517ad9ee3f6da2f31820/src/Rebus.HttpGateway/Outbound/OutboundService.cs#L139

it seems no action is taken after reading the response.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does a very simple "acknowledge" in the way that *if no error occurs, then the message is assumed to have been delivered safely to the destination queue*.

This means that the ubiquitous *at least once*-delivery guarantee holds across gateways as well, although the risk of receiving the same message twice will of course be greatly increased.

If it's important for you to process each message only once, you need to make your receiver [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) - but that's generally the rule when you're doing messaging without distributed transactions, so it's no different from scenarios where there's no HTTP gateway involved.